# How do I find the position number of an array that matches a textbox value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I hope my question isn't too incoherent. I'm a newbie.

```
var inputTextbox = document.getElementById("txtinput");
var outputTextbox = document.getElementById("txtoutput");

var upperGrade = new Array("S", "M", "C", "T")
var lowerGrade = new Array("s", "m", "c", "t")
if (inputTextbox.value.contains(upperGrade) or   inputTextbox.value.contains(lowerGrade))
{
    var arrayPosition= ??
}
```

I would like to check to see if the inputTextbox value matches a value in my array list. If it does I would like to assign the position number of the matched value to arrayPosition.

If the user's input matches the 2nd position in the upperGrade array list ("M"), then I would like to assign the number 2 to arrayPosition.

I need to do this with 'if' statements and without using loops.

Comment: Is `indexOf()` what you want? [More Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

Comment: Does this make sense? 


   int index = upperGrade.indexOf("M")


Would index be assigned the value of 2? Since "M" is the 2nd position in the upperGrade array list?

Comment: More or less. Actually, the index counting starts at `0`. AND, you would always get `1` as result, so you should use the value from the `inputText`. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var inputTextbox = document.getElementById("txtinput");
var outputTextbox = document.getElementById("txtoutput");

var upperGrade = new Array("S", "M", "C", "T")
//var lowerGrade = new Array("s", "m", "c", "t") no need to have another array just for lower case AS LONG AS IT'S THE SAME LETTERS

var pos = upperGrade.indexOf(inputTextbox.value.toUpperCase()); // pos will be -1 if not found
```

Note that index (the position) starts at `0`. So `M` would be at position `1`

Assuming that you want to output the position inside `outputTextbox`

```
outputTextbox.value = (pos >= 0) ? pos : 'NOT FOUND';
// As RobG said, if you want the 'actual' position, you can use it like this:
// outputTextbox.value = ++pos || 'NOT FOUND';
```

If the value from `inputTextbox` is in the `upperGrade` array, the `outputTextbox` will be filled with the position. Else, `NOT FOUND` will be the content of it.

Comment: The OP wants the index from 1, so `outputTextbox.value = ++pos || 'NOT FOUND'` will do.

Comment: Great this is exactly what I was looking for! You didn't even need the use of an if statement!  Thank you.

I don't understand why your answer got  a thumbs down, or why my questions keep getting thumbs down. I need to get my rep up so I can give everyone a thumbs up to counter all the negative people on here!